# predic8 wsdl parser stops after reading include xsd statement

Tags: java, parsing, soap, xsd, wsdl

The predicate wsdl parser seems to stop after opening the include of a wsd file.  The include is inside the types section.

> import com.predic8.wsdl.*; //This is the XML-parser I am using

I see this because it works when I put the types section at the end of the wsdl document:

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:sch="com.xxxsys.webservices" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="com.xxxsys.webservices" targetNamespace="com.xxxsys.webservices">
<wsdl:message name="createMandateResponse">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:createMandateResponse" name="parameters"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="createMandateRequest">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:createMandate" name="parameters"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="checkMandateResponse">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:checkMandateResponse" name="parameters"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="checkMandateRequest">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:checkMandate" name="parameters"/>
</wsdl:message> 
<wsdl:message name="availableResponse">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:availableResponse" name="parameters"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="availableRequest">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:available" name="parameters"/>
</wsdl:message> 
<!--
<wsdl:message name="GeneralFault">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:GeneralFault" name="fault"/> 
</wsdl:message>
-->
<wsdl:portType name="DMSPort">
    <wsdl:operation name="createMandate">
        <wsdl:input message="tns:createMandateRequest" name="createMandateRequest" />
        <wsdl:output message="tns:createMandateResponse" name="createMandateResponse"/>
        <!--<wsdl:fault message="tns:GeneralFault" name="GeneralFault" />-->
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="checkMandate">
        <wsdl:input message="tns:checkMandateRequest" name="checkMandateRequest" /> 
        <wsdl:output message="tns:checkMandateResponse" name="checkMandateResponse"/>
        <!--<wsdl:fault message="tns:GeneralFault" name="GeneralFault" />-->
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="available">
        <wsdl:input message="tns:availableRequest" name="availableRequest" />   
        <wsdl:output message="tns:availableResponse" name="availableResponse"/>
        <!--<wsdl:fault message="tns:GeneralFault" name="GeneralFault" />-->
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:binding name="DMSPortSoap11" type="tns:DMSPort">
    <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="createMandate">
        <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
        <wsdl:input name="createMandateRequest">
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:input>   
        <wsdl:output name="createMandateResponse">
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="checkMandate">
        <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
            <wsdl:input name="checkMandateRequest">
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:input>           
        <wsdl:output name="checkMandateResponse">
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="available">
        <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
            <wsdl:input name="availableRequest">
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:input>           
        <wsdl:output name="availableResponse">
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="DMSService">
    <wsdl:port binding="tns:DMSPortSoap11" name="DMSPortSoap11">
        <soap:address location="http://localhost:8481/ws"/>
    </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
<wsdl:types>    
<!-- <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">-->
    <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="com.xxxsys.webservices">
    <!-- <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="com.xxxsys.webservices" targetNamespace="com.xxxsys.webservices" elementFormDefault="qualified">-->
    <!-- <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="com.xxxsys.webservices">-->
        <include schemaLocation="DMS.xsd"/>
        <!--<import namespace="com.xxxsys.webservices" schemaLocation="DMS.xsd"/>-->
    </xs:schema>
</wsdl:types>
```

The xsd file looks like this:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="com.xxxsys.webservices"
       targetNamespace="com.xxxsys.webservices" elementFormDefault="qualified">

<xs:element name="createMandate">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="firstname" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="lastname" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="birthdate" type="xs:date"/>
            <xs:element name="iban" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="bic" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="newcustomer" type="xs:boolean"/>
            <xs:element name="templateid" type="xs:int"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType> 
</xs:element>


<xs:element name="createMandateResponse">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="mandatestatus" type="xs:string"/>    
            <xs:element name="mandateid" type="xs:int"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>    
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="checkMandate">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="mandateid" type="xs:int"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType> 
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="checkMandateResponse">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="mandatestatus" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType> 
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="available">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType> 
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="availableResponse">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="isAvailable" type="xs:boolean"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType> 
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="GeneralFault">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="message" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType> 
</xs:element>
```

I would like to be able to process wsdl files that have the types section with an include at the top. And thus change the wsdl file back so it is normal.

Answer (score 0):

I just found out by looking at another question that it has to be <xs:include schemaLocation="DMS.xsd"/> Now everything works as expected.

See also [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40127582/include-an-xsd-in-wsdl)